# How to make the background move in a platform game?

Tags: java, swing

I am making a simple platform game in Java Swing. Naturally I want some platforms to be too large for 1 screen and I have the following question: what is the best way to make the background move when the character controlled by the player approaches the edge of the screen? In fact not just the background but the whole game content (opponents, bricks etc.)? Surely there must be a better way than just uploading a new image and repainting everything whenever the character moves by 1 pixel. I hope i worded this in an understandable way, I tried to look it up on this site and others but no luck so far. Thx in advance.

Comment: Are you using an image for a background? You should be overriding the `paintComponent` method in a `JPanel` and drawing your pixels directly using the `Graphics` class. The general rule of thumb, though, is don't optimize unless you need to - so try the way you think best and, if it doesn't work, we can help you more with a small example of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of platform game is called a [side scroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-scrolling_video_game).

Basically, you create an image wider or taller than your JPanel.  You use Java image processing to crop a piece of the image and display it in the JPanel.

After a unit of time, you crop a different piece of the image and display it in the JPanel.  This happens so fast that it appears that the image is scrolling.

You have to model your game player, bricks, and any other objects in the game.  You have to draw these objects after you draw the background.

Check out chapter 12 of [Killer Game Programming in Java](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/).  You will probably need to read the earlier chapters first, so chapter 12 makes sense.  If you want to do lots of Java game development, buy the book.

Comment: Ok so i upload the whole map at the beginning and then paint only the current fragments right? Only question, what exactly do You mean by "After a unit of time, you crop a different piece of the image and display it in the JPanel."? Specifically, what period of time, or do You simply mean that I do it when the character is nearing the edge of the screen?

Comment: @MountainThatCodes: Let's say you want your game to run at 20 frames per second.  That means you have 50 milliseconds to generate a frame.  The unit of time is 50 milliseconds.  You have to determine how much of your background you want to scroll, how far your game player can move in 50 milliseconds.

Comment: @MountainThatCodes: It depends on how big your map is.  If it's a true side scroller, where your background repeats every 2,000 pixels, you can load the whole image in the beginning.  If your game world is huge, you'll have to use tiling, and build an image slightly bigger than your JPanel.

Comment: Okay final question, how exactly do I handle non-static stuff that is currently off the screen? For example let's say I have an opponent who moves from left to right and vice versa somewhere the player can't see at the moment. Do i update his (opponent's) location according to his movement and check whether he is currently on the frame and then decide whether to paint him or not? What if he is only partly on the screen? What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: @MountainThatCodes: Generally, objects are responsible for drawing themselves.  You have to keep track of where objects are, and your object draw method converts game coordinates to JPanel coordinates and determines whether or not the object is located in the JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

I think the above answer is a valid way to do it, but if you would like another. You can cast your Graphics object into a Graphics2D object which you can then translate a distance from the origin. when you do this everything you draw from the Graphics object will be translated

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
   super.paint(g);

   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
   g2d.translate(character.x,character.y);

   background.render(g);
   character.render(g);
}
```

Although this does require to repaint objects that may not have necessarily moved. And when dealing with large maps it can become a problem. But I always  try to only render the objects that are on the screen and a few that might partially on screen. A tutorial that shows a way to do this is on youtube

[Tutorial](http://youtu.be/1obIPePxZfg?list=PL7l7E2n5iVj9yVW0I6MYLI_lhTPA-ebOO)